# Error CS1950 y CS1503 al utilizar Try - catch

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. Con el animo de mejorar el código para manejar excepciones, estoy implementando un try - catch. Este es el código:

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Anhos", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasAnhos")]
    public List<LicenciaAnos> GetLlantasSalidasAnhos()
    {
        // 2024-02-08: Creo esta lista como alternativo en caso de presentarse una excepción
        List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = new List<LicenciaAnos>() 
        {
            2023,
            2024
        };
        try
        {
            var q = from a in context.LlanSalidasLlantas
                    orderby a.fecha.Year
                    group a by a.fecha.Year into GrupoA
                    select new LicenciaAnos
                    {
                        Ano = GrupoA.Key
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            return AnhoActual;
        }
    }
```

Los datos 2023 y 2024 aparecen resaltados en color rojo, por lo cual, procedo a oprimir F5 para ejecutar el código y validar a que se debe el error. Tanto para el 2023 como para el 2024 aparecen dos errores, los cuales son:

Error   CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List.Add(LicenciaAnos)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'AnalistaFlotasDAL.LicenciaAnos'

El método me debe retornar una lista del tipo List, la cual tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
public class LicenciaAnos
{
    [Key]
    public int Ano { get; set; }
}
```

Agradecemos por favor nos indiquen las cosas a corregir para poder implementar el try - catch, ya que veo esto como una muy buena forma de mejorar el código que tengo en la actualidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es que estás guardando enteros en una lista de tipo **LicenciaAnos**, lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = new List<LicenciaAnos>() 
{
    new LicenciaAnos()
    {
        Ano = 2023
    },
    new LicenciaAnos()
    {
        Ano = 2024
    }
};
```

Aquí construyes una lista que almacenará dos objetos de tipo **LicenciaAnos** donde el primer objeto tendrá a su **propiedad Ano** con el valor **2023** y el segundo objeto tendrá su **propiedad Ano** con el valor **2024**.

Answer (score 3):

Desde C# 12, se puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = [
    new() { Ano = 2013 }, 
    new() { Ano = 2014 }
];
```

---

También puedes realizar un conversión implícita, digamos que tu clase es:

```
public class LicenciaAnos
{
    public int Ano { get; set; }

    //conversión implícita desde un int a LicenciaAnos
    public static implicit operator LicenciaAnos(int ano) => new(){ Ano = ano };
}
```

Con lo cual ahora puedes declarar la lista de esta manera:

```
List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = [2013, 2014];
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta sintaxis no es valida:

```
List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = new List<LicenciaAnos>() 
{
    2023,
    2024
};
```

Leamos tu codigo.. estas diciendo que AnhoActual (porque no año??) es un objeto de tipo Lista que contiene objetos del tipo LicenciaAnos (otra vez, o todos son anos, o todos son anho. o mejor todos son años)..

Pero luego, en la generacion simplificada (y ahi esta tu problema) del objeto le pasas una lista de numeros...

Veamos la definicion de LicenciaAnos

```
public class LicenciaAnos
{
    [Key]
    public int Ano { get; set; }
}
```

Pues, es una lista de numeros... correcto.. pero tu lista.. es una lista de objetos!!!!

en realidad, cuando escibiste esto:

```
List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = new List<LicenciaAnos>() 
{
    2023,
    2024
};
```

en realidad, usaste un poco de sugar syntax, y lo que en realidad hiciste es:

```
List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = new List<LicenciaAnos>();
AnohActual.add(2023);
AnohActual.add(2024);
```

Pero, otra vez, ese 2023 no es un objeto del tipo LicenciaAnos, es un numero!!!!

Entonces, en realidad tu codigo, sin azucar, deberia ser:

```
List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = new List<LicenciaAnos>();
AnohActual.add(new LicenciaAnos(2023));
AnohActual.add(new LicenciaAnos(2024));
```

Siempre y cuando, LicenciaAnos tenga un constructor para llenar ese dato.. si no.. tampoco va a funcionar... es todavia mas complicada la sintaxis..

Pero bueno, supongamos que si.. y agreguemos azucar a ese codigo:

```
List<LicenciaAnos> AnhoActual = new List<LicenciaAnos>()
{
    new LicenciaAnos(2023),
    new LicenciaAnos(2024)
}
```